# Returning timeout from DataView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am converting code from visual basic to C#, the code converted to C# is as follows:

```
if (txt_Username.Text == string.Empty || txt_pwd.Text == string.Empty || txt_Installation.Text == string.Empty)
{
    lbl_AlertDanger.Visible = true;
    lbl_AlertDanger.Text = "<center><strong>ERROR</strong> -Ingrese Credenciales</center>";
}
else if (txt_Username.Text.Length > 1 && txt_pwd.Text.Length > 1 && txt_Installation.Text.Length >= 1) 
{
    try
    {
        ds_Student_Login.SelectParameters["Installation"].DefaultValue = txt_Installation.Text.Trim();
        ds_Student_Login.SelectParameters["Username"].DefaultValue = txt_Username.Text.Trim().ToLower();
        ds_Student_Login.SelectParameters["Pwd"].DefaultValue = txt_pwd.Text.Trim();
        ds_Student_Login.DataBind();

        DataView o_Selecte_UserData = ((DataView)(ds_Student_Login.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)));

        foreach (DataRow o_UserData in o_Selecte_UserData.Table.Rows)
        {
            if (o_UserData["Result_Cd"] == "OK")
            {
                HttpCookie v_CkLastLogin = new HttpCookie("FM_LastLogin");
                v_CkLastLogin.Values["Username"] = txt_Username.ToString();
                v_CkLastLogin.Values["Installation"] = txt_Installation.ToString();
                v_CkLastLogin.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
                Response.Cookies.Add(v_CkLastLogin);

                Session["s_Username"] = o_UserData["Username"];

                Response.Redirect("LSProducts.aspx", true);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lbl_AlertDanger.Visible = true;
        lbl_AlertDanger.Text = "<center><strong>ERROR</strong> - " + ex.Message + </center>";
    }
}
```

the "Result_Cd" is a response that is obtained from a stored procedure, I'm getting an error in this line

```
DataView o_Selecte_UserData = ((DataView)(ds_Student_Login.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)));
```

and it says:

> Execution timeout timed out. The time-out period elapsed before the completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Why with VB.net if it leaves me why with C#?

Comment: What is stack trace? How many records do you have in `ds_Student_Login`?

Comment: At the moment I only have one user